# Render Laravel 7 component programmatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have a Laravel 7 component which looks like this

```
class Input extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $title;
    public $value;
    public $type = 'text';

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name, $title)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->value = \Form::getValueAttribute($name);
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.fields.input');
    }
}
```

I can render the field in my Blade component like this:

`<x-input name="name" :title="__('My field')" />`

I have a requirement to create and render the field in code, I've tried the following:

```
$field = new Input('name', 'My field');
$field->render();
```

This returns an error:

`Undefined variable: title`

I can see that the render function is called but the public properties are not made available to the view. How would I render the component with the public properties?

Comment: what is your class name?

Comment: The class is called "Input"

Comment: no harm in test so update your laravel to 7.9 and your code be like this: <x-input name="name" :title="{{ __('My field') }}" /> if it didnt work remove colon before title

Comment: The field renders fine in a Blade template, I need to know how to render it programmatically. I'm creating a system to let the user create their own fields and I need to render them from code rather than a fixed template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this, it also works with anonymous component. Put this in your helper file.

```php
/**
 * Render a blade component.
 * @param string $name Component name, exclude component folder (i.e use "card" instead of "components.card")
 * @param array $props Component properties
 * @param array $attributes Component attributes
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
 */
function viewComponent($name, $props = [], $attributes = []) {
    $className = collect(explode('.', $name))->map(function($part) {
        return \Str::studly($part);
    })->join('\\');
    $className = "App\\View\\Components\\{$className}";
    if(class_exists($className)) {
        $reflection = (new \ReflectionClass($className))->getConstructor();
        $parameters = [];
        foreach ($reflection->getParameters() as $param) {
            $parameters[] = $props[$param->name] ?? $param->getDefaultValue();
        }
        $component = new $className(...$parameters);
        $component->withAttributes($attributes);
        return $component->render()->with($component->data());
    }

    $props['attributes'] = new \Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag($attributes);
    return view("components.$name", $props);
}
```

### Usage

```php
viewComponent('input', [
    'name' => 'name',
    'title' => 'My Field',
]);

// if you want custom attribute
viewComponent('input', [
    'name' => 'name',
    'title' => 'My Field',
], [
    'autocomplete' => 'off',
    'data-custom' => 'custom attribute',
]);
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this, it works for me in laravel 8, and I checked `data` function exists in laravel 7

```
$field = new Input('name', 'My field');
$field->render()->with($field->data());
```

** data function include methods, properties and attributes of Component.

Comment: this is amazing! thank you! for my use case i wanted the output as a string so i did:
`$pre_rendered_component_as_html_string = $header_component->render()->with($header_component->data())->render();`

Comment: @jakedowns I needed too, but I found it more poetic to call `toHtml()` at the end, which does exactly the same in Laravel 8 at least :D

Answer (score 7):

The [last release](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.80.0) (v.8.80) of Laravel should help you achieve what you're trying to do with the [pull #40425](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40425)

```php
Blade::render('<x-input name="name" :title="$title" />', ['title' => __('My field')]);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is now possible using the `Blade::renderComponent` method.
So this is how you should do it:

```php
echo Blade::renderComponent(new Input('name', 'My field'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Manually add variables to the view. Otherwise it won't work

I reported this but it's not considered an issue:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32429

Answer (score 1):

Just add the properties to view manually and it will work. If not make the properties private but it should not have influence to that. Just my implementation.

```
     /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view(
            'components.fields.input',
            ['name' => $this->name, 'title' => $this->title]
        );
    }
```

Comment: This way you lose the logics inside app/View/Components/*