# How can I sent request to laravel component method?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 I create a new component with command :

```
php artisan make:component  Frontend/Nomination
```

and I use it in my blade.php file as :

```
<x-frontend.nomination :defaultNomination="$defaultNomination" />
```

but as functionality has ajax requests I try to put some methods inside of this component and returning json

But adding line in routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/get_nominated_photos/{nomination_id}/{current_page?}', View\Components\Frontend\Nomination::class)->name('get_nominated_photos');
```

I got error :

```
View\Components\Frontend\Nomination` was not found: Controller class `View\Components\Frontend\Nomination` for one of your routes was not found. Are you sure this controller exists and is imported correctly?
```

If there is a way to use Components in routes/web.php? If yes in which way ?

**UPDATED BLOCK # :**
looks like I set the path invalid : So I modified line :

```
Route::get('/get_nominated_photos/{nomination_id}/{current_page?}', \App\View\Components\Frontend\Nomination::class)->name('get_nominated_photos');
```

and in component file : app/View/Components/Frontend/Nomination.php
I have header :

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Frontend;

class Nomination extends Component
{
   ...
```

But I got error :

```
 Invalid route action: [App\View\Components\Frontend\Nomination].

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteAction.php:92
     88▕      */
     89▕     protected static function makeInvokable($action)
     90▕     {
     91▕         if (! method_exists($action, '__invoke')) {
  ➜  92▕             throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid route action: [{$action}].");
     93▕         }
     94▕ 
     95▕         return $action.'@__invoke';
     96▕     }

  • `App\View\Components\Frontend\Nomination` was not found: Controller class `App\View\Components\Frontend\Nomination` for one of your routes was not found. Are you sure this controller exists and is imported correctly?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the View/Components folder. Is the component there somewhere? If so, what are its contents?

Comment: I believe it should be `\View\Components` not `View\Components` But that being said, I'm not sure Laravel Components can be rendered like this (Based on a similar question I saw some day ago on SO)

Comment: Please look at UPDATED BLOCK

Comment: The error explains it expect `_invoke` method since you're using [single action controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#single-action-controllers) syntax. You should specify the method `render`

Comment: I confirm what I was saying before, I tried and got a lot of issues. You can see some tries here to render a component out of blade: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484068/render-laravel-7-component-programmatically What you're trying will simply won't work unless your component doesn't have props and doesn't use slot.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you cannot render a Laravel Compoment that way unless your component doesn't have props and doesn't use slot.

The [last release](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.80.0) (v.8.80) of Laravel should help you achieve what you're trying to do with the [pull #40425](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40425)

```php
Route::get(
    '/get_nominated_photos/{nomination_id}/{current_page?}', 
    fn($nomination_id) => Blade::render('<x-frontend.nomination :defaultNomination="$defaultNomination" />', ['defaultNomination' => $nomination_id])  
)->name('get_nominated_photos');
```